# django project with heroku: application error

Tags: django, heroku, web-deployment

I successfully deploy the project to Heroku. but when I run Heroku open it throws Application error 
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

my logs is here

```
(dj12) λ heroku logs
2018-07-05T07:06:17.443987+00:00 app[api]: Initial release by user     ermiaskidanegebre@gmail.com
2018-07-05T07:06:17.443987+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user ermiaskidanegebre@gmail.com
2018-07-05T07:06:17.909289+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user ermiaskidanegebre@gmail.com
2018-07-05T07:06:17.909289+00:00 app[api]: Enable Logplex by user ermiaskidanegebre@gmail.com
2018-07-05T07:16:35.051508+00:00 app[api]: Attach DATABASE (@ref:postgresql-shaped-50056) by user ermiaskidanegebre@gmail.com
2018-07-05T07:16:35.051508+00:00 app[api]: Release v3 created by user ermiaskidanegebre@gmail.com
2018-07-05T07:24:48.143580+00:00 app[api]: Set SECRET_KEY config vars by user ermiaskidanegebre@gmail.com
2018-07-05T07:24:48.143580+00:00 app[api]: Release v4 created by user ermiaskidanegebre@gmail.com
2018-07-05T07:33:04.050618+00:00 app[api]: Set SECRET_KEY config vars by user ermiaskidanegebre@gmail.com
2018-07-05T07:33:04.050618+00:00 app[api]: Release v5 created by user ermiaskidanegebre@gmail.com
2018-07-05T07:40:34.881810+00:00 app[api]: Set EMAIL_PASSWORD config vars by user ermiaskidanegebre@gmail.com
2018-07-05T07:40:34.881810+00:00 app[api]: Release v6 created by user ermiaskidanegebre@gmail.com
2018-07-05T07:49:13.302208+00:00 app[api]: Release v7 created by user ermiaskidanegebre@gmail.com
2018-07-05T07:49:13.302208+00:00 app[api]: Set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC config vars by user ermiaskidanegebre@gmail.com
2018-07-05T07:54:43.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user ermiaskidanegebre@gmail.com
2018-07-05T07:55:09.406852+00:00 app[api]: Release v8 created by user ermiaskidanegebre@gmail.com
2018-07-05T07:55:09.406852+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 2fdb68de by user ermiaskidanegebre@gmail.com
2018-07-05T07:55:18.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2018-07-05T07:57:14.239360+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `python manage.py migrate` by user ermiaskidanegebre@gmail.com
2018-07-05T07:57:20.853528+00:00 heroku[run.2986]: State changed from starting to up
2018-07-05T07:57:20.965558+00:00 heroku[run.2986]: Awaiting client
2018-07-05T07:57:21.013142+00:00 heroku[run.2986]: Starting process with command `python manage.py migrate`
2018-07-05T07:57:26.012552+00:00 heroku[run.2986]: Process exited with status 1
2018-07-05T07:57:26.032134+00:00 heroku[run.2986]: State changed from up to complete
2018-07-05T08:01:58.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user ermiaskidanegebre@gmail.com
2018-07-05T08:02:15.941485+00:00 app[api]: Release v9 created by user ermiaskidanegebre@gmail.com
2018-07-05T08:02:15.941485+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 8a0e03de by user ermiaskidanegebre@gmail.com
2018-07-05T08:02:25.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2018-07-05T08:03:43.462294+00:00 heroku[run.1120]: Awaiting client
2018-07-05T08:03:43.510884+00:00 heroku[run.1120]: Starting process with command `python manage.py migrate`
2018-07-05T08:03:43.859691+00:00 heroku[run.1120]: State changed from starting to up
 2018-07-05T08:03:37.888541+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `python manage.py migrate` by user ermiaskidanegebre@gmail.com
2018-07-05T08:03:53.506152+00:00 heroku[run.1120]: Process exited with status 0
2018-07-05T08:03:53.525335+00:00 heroku[run.1120]: State changed from up to complete
2018-07-05T08:13:52.212453+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=django-ecommerce-2.herokuapp.com request_id=750bffb9-e6bb-4ea7-94bd-09772529bf3c fwd="82.26.20.87" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-07-05T08:13:52.636447+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=django-ecommerce-2.herokuapp.com request_id=be57a379-0d82-4251-9218-049d3cdfb9a6 fwd="82.26.20.87" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-07-05T08:57:48.239032+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=django-ecommerce-2.herokuapp.com request_id=e5708b4e-1ef6-4167-a70a-0a99c9b8aecf fwd="82.26.20.87" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
 2018-07-05T08:57:48.702316+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=django-ecommerce-2.herokuapp.com request_id=d92730e4-c5e9-4570-a709-311a07e0e3dc fwd="82.26.20.87" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-07-05T09:11:36.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user ermiaskidanegebre@gmail.com
2018-07-05T09:11:53.696459+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 2993315c by user ermiaskidanegebre@gmail.com
 2018-07-05T09:11:53.696459+00:00 app[api]: Release v10 created by user ermiaskidanegebre@gmail.com
2018-07-05T09:12:03.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2018-07-05T09:32:26.285646+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=django-ecommerce-2.herokuapp.com request_id=08b476e4-c7f9-43b4-b706-9d44d3b8c8c1 fwd="82.26.20.87" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-07-05T09:32:55.648599+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=django-ecommerce-2.herokuapp.com request_id=5e4b151f-757b-49ad-8138-c47877c2c3e1 fwd="82.26.20.87" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-07-05T11:09:37.172582+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=django-ecommerce-2.herokuapp.com request_id=ea6c2402-cfe2-4cb5-a910-2b6d152174f4 fwd="82.26.20.87" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-07-05T11:10:05.085667+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=django-ecommerce-2.herokuapp.com request_id=f91cef75-167c-4160-8709-e73736384dbc fwd="82.26.20.87" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-07-05T11:10:06.448716+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=django-ecommerce-2.herokuapp.com request_id=5fa29e24-e3d1-439f-bf88-dd1f266ac85a fwd="82.26.20.87" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
 2018-07-05T11:22:38.501221+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `bash` by user ermiaskidanegebre@gmail.com
 2018-07-05T11:22:43.651327+00:00 heroku[run.8345]: Awaiting client
 2018-07-05T11:22:43.684186+00:00 heroku[run.8345]: Starting process with command `bash`
 2018-07-05T11:22:43.729572+00:00 heroku[run.8345]: State changed from starting to up
 2018-07-05T11:29:31.865357+00:00 heroku[run.8345]: Process exited with status 127
 2018-07-05T11:29:32.006562+00:00 heroku[run.8345]: State changed from up to     complete
```

my procfile

```
"web: gunicorn ecommerce2.wsgi"
```

my wsgi.py

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "ecommerce2.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

and from the documentation errors related to H14 can be fixed with *heroku ps:scale web=1* and this pop out

```
Scaling dynos... !
!    Couldn't find that process type.
```

when I check my Heroku account the Dynos in the resource is saying the below tex,  eventhough I added my Procfile successfully.

```
This app has no process types yet 
Add a Procfile to your app in order to define its process types. Learn more
```

how could I fix this issue? 
thanks for your help.

Comment: Is your file called "procfile" or "Procfile"? Are its contents really surrounded by quotes?

Comment: it is Procfile  and it is surrounded by quotes

Comment: Then take the quotes out.

Comment: thanks Daniel it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app doesn't have any process running.

You need to scale your `web` dyno with the `heroku ps:scale web=1` command.

Of course, this assumes you have configured a `web` process type in your [Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile).

Comment: Damien, I do Heroku ps:sacle web=1 in the command it throws   "Scaling dynos... !
!    Couldn't find that process type."

Comment: That means you haven't set any `web` dyno in your Procfile.

Comment: I use the heroku ps:scale web=1 to set the web dyno  or is there another way to set the dyno?

Answer (score 2):

Last time when I had this issue it was related to requirement not found. update your requirements.txt file from your local.

Also what you want to do is in your settings.py

```
DEBUG = False
DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS = True
```

Add these lines for production. This will propogate error to log. There you can see why you are getting application error.

(I am willing to bet its a some missing package. Let me know what it was.)

Comment: Ojas Kale, well I do but the error is still the same. Incase I miss the steps for the requirements.txt,  I use pip freeze > requirements.txt and for debug_propagate I git add the modified file, then commit it , then push to Heroku.

Comment: try adding these lines to settings.py and see the logs in heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Today I faced the same error. In my root directory, I had Procfile without any extention but when I opened the code in visual studio code, the Procfile had the extension .txt and was present as "Procfile.txt". I just removed the .txt from the file and saved it. This resolved my error.

You can refer to my post for more clarification:

[Getting application error while running the python app on heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64364849/getting-application-error-while-running-the-python-app-on-heroku?noredirect=1#comment113819255_64364849)

Comment: I didn't change anything in Procfile, I kept it same "web: gunicorn script1:app" as mentioned in my post. I was stuck with this issue for hours.

Comment: If you are able to successfully push the changes to git but still not able to open the application. 1. Check Procfile is saved as a file and not as notebook. 2. Your requirements.txt contains all the libraries which you are using in your scipts. 3. Your runtime.txt contains the python version which you are using on your system.