# Getting application error while running the python app on heroku

Tags: python, git, heroku

I am trying to deploy a simple python app to heroku but I am getting application error while running the command "heroku open".

Below is the list of files and folders in my root directory of the application.

[image: files_list]

Inside my Procfile, I have written the below code:

```
      web: gunicorn script1:app
```

This is the first time I am trying to deploy the app to heroku. Below is the sequence of commands I am using for the same:

1. Create 3 files in my root folder, requirements.txt, Procfile, runtime.txt.
2. Open command prompt, navigate to root folder, run command "heroku login" - Login successful after providing the email.
3. "heroku create myappname" - Created the app successfully.
4. "git init" - Created the .git folder in my root path.
5. "git add ." - Added all the files in the current directory to the git repository successfuly.
6. "git config --global user.email "myemail@gmail.com" - Successfully authenticated.
7. "git config --global user.name "username"
8. "git commit -m "first commit""
9. "heroku git:remote --app myappname"
10. "git push heroku master" - Successfully detected and deployed the app with a message:   Verifying deploy... done.
11. "heroku open" - Whenever I run this command I get Application error.

Everything went smoothly till step 10. But, whenever I try opening the app, it gives application error in the browser.

I searched the internet and tried 2 solutions but none of them worked for me:

1. To run the command before opening heroku - "heroku ps:scale web=1"
2. To change the run method in the scripts file as :

   ```
    if __name__ == "__main__":
               port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000))
               app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=port)
   ```

I don't know what I am doing wrong, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Screenshot of error:
[image]

Logs:

heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/"
status=503

[image]

Comment: what more is in the log? Likely the actuall error when starting the server will be visible too

Comment: I posted the screenshot of the logs.

Comment: 1. `git push heroku master` this pushes the local master branch to the remote master branch. Verify that you are locally also working on the master branch. 2. `web: gunicorn script1:app` don't use gunicorn. Use it after you verified it is working. gunicorn doesn't print out a lot of the errror messages. Instead change that to: `web: python script1.py` 3. `No web processes running` go to http://herokuapp.com/ then to your app, select resources and activate your app there.

Comment: yes, I am working on the master branch locally. I verified this through the command "git branch". I changed "web: gunicorn script1:app" to "web: python script1.py", but it doesn't seems to work. I also went to the heroku dashboard--> selected myapp --> view app. It results in the same error.

Comment: I figured out the issue. Even though the Procfile didn't show any extension in my root directory, it was saved as text document. When I opened the code in my IDE visual studio code, I saw the "Procfile.txt" was present, I renamed the file and deleted the .txt from the name. I deleted .git repository and carried out the above steps again. And I am able to successfully launch the application on heroku. Posting this answer, if it would be helpful to someone else.